# get the locale languge of i18n from pinia store

Tags: vue.js, pinia, vue-i18n

i'm trying to get the value of the i18n lcale language from my pinia store
but i'm getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    const pinia = createPinia()
    app.use(pinia)
This will fail in production.
```

Here is the i18n/index.js code

```
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { useaStore } from "../stores/countdowns";

const store = useaStore()
const { language } = storeToRefs(store)

import { createI18n } from "vue-i18n";
import en from './locales/en'
import ar from './locales/ar'


export default createI18n({
  locale: language,
  fallbackLocale: 'ar',
  legacy: false,
  globalInjection: true,
  messages: { en, ar }
})
```

Comment: It's more straightforward to change i18n locale in an action where you set store value

Comment: Composables (such as useStore, storeToRefs, etc.) should only be called synchronously in `<script setup>` or the setup() hook of a component.

Comment: @EstusFlask how i can do that?

Comment: So what should i do in my case to make it works? @yoduh

Comment: When your app is first created does your store have a default language value?  You should just use that same value when calling `createI18n`.  Otherwise, [change the locale](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/advanced/composition.html#locale-changing) within your root component (usually App.vue) when it is created/mounted

Comment: Yes it has a default {language: “en”} and i’m still getting this error @yoduh

Comment: By setting i18n.global.locale inside pinia action. See  https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/essentials/scope.html#local-scope-1

Comment: i dont want the locale language comes from i18n to pinia, i need to store the i18n locale language in my pinia store so i can let usere switch betweeen languags by changing the languge value that in my store @EstusFlask

Comment: Can you please make it in code so i can understand it better? Thank you @EstusFlask

Comment: I posted the explanation

Answer (score 0):

Pinia store composables are primarily intended to postpone the instantiation of a store and avoid this error, they aren't supposed to be used at top module level.

Since `createI18n` options accept non-reactive `locale` string, the usage of the store would make no sense here.

`locale` can be changed either from store actions, also may need to be called set initial value:

```
actions: {
  setLang(lang) {
    this.lang = lang;
   i18n.global.locale = lang;
  },
  ...
```

Or the values can be synchronized from the outside, can be done inside root component:

```
const store = useaStore()
watch(
  () => store.lang, 
  () => { i18n.global.locale = store.lang; }
  { immediate: true }
)
```